# Scheduling Informatica IICS taskflow

Tags: unix, schedule, informatica, informatica-cloud, iics

I have a requirement to run a taskflow like below

every 15 minutes - from 1 AM to 3 AM everyday

every 2 hours - from 3 AM to 1 AM everyday

Could you please help me know, if this can be achieved through IICS, or a scheduler, or through Unix scripting

Answer (score 0):

Informatica scheduler is very limited. It's better to use dedicated tool, like Airflow, Autosys or Control-M.

Basically in such scenario I'd create three tasks/schedules:

- one for the "every 15 minutes - from 1 AM to 3 AM everyday", CRON expression would be `*/15 1-3 * * *`
- second for "every 2nd hour from 3 AM to 11 PM everyday": `0 3-23/2 * * *`
- third for "1 AM everyday": `0 1 * * *`

Use https://crontab.guru/ to verify expressions or work on other ones.